# An elementary question $(1^n)^\frac 1n=1$

Tags: complex-numbers

$(1^n)^\frac 1n=(1^{(\frac1n)})^n$?
The left is has n different values, while the right is just one.
So, $(x^a)^b=(x^b)^a$ is wrong in $C$?

Comment: It is not so much *wrong*, you just have to be careful about what exactly all the exponentations mean, and be clear that it holds only in nice cases. For instance, it still always holds if $a,b$ are both integers.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if we define $a^{1/b}$ as the solutions to the polynomial $x^b-a=0$, you will find there are $b$ unique solutions in $\mathbb C$.

On the other hand, if you define $a^{1/b}$ as the positive $b^{\text{th}}$ root of $a$ when $a$ is positive, then there is no problem.

For example, consider the following:

$$x=1^{1/2}=\begin{cases}0=x^2-1&\implies x=\pm1\\x=\sqrt1&\implies x=1\end{cases}$$

So depending on how you define exponentiation for non-whole values, the answers come out differently.

Your specific numbers are known as the [roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity), and you might find some interesting stuff there.